# Using two Select Form Boxes but only one appears

Tags: jquery, css, stylesheet

**I have used two select form boxes and the second should appear below instead it does not display but the rest of the content does**

I have copied the code at the top of the page and it appears but reformats the page. I want it to appear just below the first :/

HTML:

```
      <select name="Category" required="required">
      <option value="" title="Category">Category</option>
      <option value="CAT1">CAT1</option>

      <select name="Location" required="required">
      <option value="" title="Location">Select Location</option>
      <option value="Worldwide">Worldwide</option>
```

css

```
select {
padding:1.2em;
margin: 0em;
background: #e74c3c;
color:#ffffff;
outline:none;
display: inline-block;
-webkit-appearance:none;
-moz-appearance:none;
appearance:none;
cursor:pointer;
clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Select tag needs to be closed...This should work..

```
  <select name="Category" required="required">
  <option value="" title="Category">Category</option>
  <option value="CAT1">CAT1</option>
    </select>
  <select name="Location" required="required">
  <option value="" title="Location">Select Location</option>
  <option value="Worldwide">Worldwide</option>
  </select>
```

In case you want them one below the other place them in seperate  divs